# How to POST request in Switch Case

Tags: java, android, http-post, httprequest

I want to POST a request in multiple switch case but there comes error in every case while calling the request. Please anybody help me out! Here is my code:

```
public class BeaconListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private ArrayList<Beacon> beacons;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Context context;
  public HttpPost httpPost;

  public BeaconListAdapter(Context context) {

    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.beacons = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context= context;

  }

    if (beacon.getRssi() < -20 && beacon.getRssi() > -85) {

      String query = "?deviceMacAddress=" + info.getMacAddress() + "&beaconMacAddress=" +  maxBeacon.getMacAddress();
//            new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://113.20.19.234:92/api/Beacon/Get" + query);*/
      fbmajor= maxBeacon.getMajor();
      switch (fbmajor) {

        case 1333:
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, I1.class);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent);
          new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + query);
          Log.i("Call", query);
          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

          Log.e("Tag11",URL);
          break;

        case 51185:
          Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, I2.class);
          intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent2);
          new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + query);
          Log.i("Call", query);
          httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
          break;

        case 51292:
          Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, I3.class);
          intent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent3);
          new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + query);
          Log.i("Call", query);
          httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
          Log.e("Tag3", URL);
          break;

        case 14948:
          Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, I4.class);
          intent4.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent4);
          new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + query);
          Log.i("Call", query);
          httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
          Log.e("Tag4", URL);
          break;

         }
  }

  public String POST(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

      // create HttpClient
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      // make GET request to the given URL
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpPost(url));

      // receive response as inputStream
      inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

      // convert inputstream to string
      if(inputStream != null)
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
      else
        result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
      result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

  }

  private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

      return POST(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "POST!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      //etResponse.setText(result);

    }
  }
```

Here the error comes in the switch case in the http Post line. So the url is not getting call. Anyone have the solution?

Comment: please show error log

Comment: '11-04 19:28:30.019  15145-15145/com.estimote.examples.demos E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.estimote.examples.demos, PID: 15145
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:82)
            at com.estimote.examples.demos.adapters.BeaconListAdapter.bind(BeaconListAdapter.java:207)
            at com.estimote.examples.demos.adapters.BeaconListAdapter.getView(BeaconListAdapter.java:139)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2353)'

Comment: The error is there in switch case in 'httppost=new httPost(url)'

Comment: what is the value of url?

Comment: That is what i am asking how to assign  the value to url. Value is http://192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + query

Comment: Then create a url variable on top with a value of "192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" and every creation of HttpPost, use httpPost = new HttpPost(url + query);

Comment: I have done this but the error is same!!

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do  url ="192.168.137.121:1010/api/History"

Comment: I have tried doing this also but is not working. It is not taking the url from POST method !

Comment: Now the error is 'Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 192.168.137.121:1010/api/History?deviceMacAddress=a8:1b:5a:b7:11:49&beaconMacAddress=[E7:15:2C:A0:05:21]'

Comment: Can you cross check for spaces? Is URL working without params?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to test your link is it working? You can use postman to test your post url.

If it works fine, you might want to try

> URLEncoder.encode(url);
>
> String url = "192.168.137.121:1010/api/History" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");

Comment: The error is this now Runtime error and'Now the error is 'Illegal character in scheme at index 0: 192.168.137.121:1010/api/History?deviceMacAddress=a8:1b:5a:b7:11:49&beaconMacAddress=[E7:15:2C:A0:05:21]'

Comment: do you have any blank space in front of the url?

Comment: Yes i did that now there is ' Connection to http://192.168.137.121:1010 refused' error!